# How do you see the whole MSDN content tree these days?

Tags: msdn

Until 10 years ago, I used to read a lot of MSDN everyday from the local .CHM file that came with the Visual Studio installation of your choice.

I still read the Web version of MSDN but I get the feeling that I am not in control because I don't know how to locate the topic I am reading again, except for bookmarking it in my browser. I would like to be able to see the entire MSDN content tree so as to get a perspective of the way content is organized.

This will also enable me to see regular columns that I might be interested in reading on a regular basis. Back in the day, I used to love reading the usability column from Scott Berkun and a few others. I would love to get back to reading MSDN with some feeling of control as to what I am reading as I still find reading the MSDN an immensely enjoyable activity.

How do I do that?

Comment: By "MSDN", do you mean the MSDN Magazine, the MSDN Library or both?  If you're specifically interested in the Magazine, are you simply looking for local copies or are you asking about a comprehensive content tree that spans issues and years?